# How to work with Google Spanner Date type in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, google-cloud-spanner

I have multiple tables in Google Cloud Spanner with columns of type *Date*. Inserting entries with specified dates is not a problem, and reflects appropriately in the database. However, retrieving entries from the database into the Javascript frontend is where the issue lies. I can't seem to figure out in which format these date fields are.

My (Google Cloud Functions) code retrieves a customer from the database as follows:

```
async function fetch(database, query) {
  query.json = true;
  try {
    const [rows] = await database.run(query);
    return rows;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("ERROR:", error);
    throw error;
  } finally {
    database.close();
  }
}

exports.fetchCustomer = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const database = instance.database(data.dataset);
  let address = fetch(database, {
    sql: `SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE addressId = '${data.id}'`,
  });
  let customer = fetch(database, {
    sql: `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerId = '${data.id}'`,
  });

  try {
    [address, customer] =
      await Promise.all([address, customer]);
    return [address[0], customer[0]];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("ERROR:", error);
    throw error;
  }
});
```

On the front-end side, I have:

```
const fetchCustomer = httpsCallable(firebaseFunctions, 'fetchCustomer');
await fetchCustomer({dataset: this.dataset, id: this.customerId})
.then((res) => {
  this.address = res.data[0];
  this.customer = res.data[1];
}
```

The object `this.customer` then has a property *dateOfBirth* which seems to be an infinitely nested object, which I can't make sense of. How can I convert that property to a String with the format 'yyyy-mm-dd' or any other appropriate date format?

Any advice or information on the matter would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This sample has an example (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/samples/spanner-query-with-date-parameter#spanner_query_with_date_parameter-nodejs):

```
  rows.forEach(row => {
    const date = row[2]['value'];
    const json = row.toJSON();
    console.log(
      `VenueId: ${json.VenueId}, VenueName: ${json.VenueName},` +
        ` LastContactDate: ${JSON.stringify(date).substring(1, 11)}`
    );   });
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a bit, but the example is very specific and hard-coded. In my case, I am using a fetch function to retrieve rows from multiple tables and it is always immediately converted to JSON. I will update my question to give more detail, but I need a way to work with the date field after it has been converted to JSON.